# Materialize Css : select in card

Tags: css, select, drop-down-menu, materialize

I am trying to use select in a card.

Problem is that when the select list is open and it should overflow outside of card, it doesn't.

The overflowing part is hidden/blocked/gone.

I've tried following and failed:

- overflow:visible
- increasing z-index
- changing position to relative (this would dynamically increase the card to fit the select - not desired outcome)

on a side question, is it not a proper material design to use select (or other inputs) in a card?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the `.card` class has the style `overflow: hidden` on it. If you remove this from your card, it will allow the content of the select to flow outside of its boundaries.

Adding `overflow: visible` to `.card` works. Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqeYOy). Just make sure you are correctly overriding the `.card` class styles.

Answer (score -1):

You have to initialize the select manually 
something like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').formSelect();
});
```

Or

```
 M.AutoInit();
```

If you dont want to initialize manually on pages all just add above one line in your script tag.

follow their documentation https://materializecss.com/select.html navigate to the initialization section

https://materializecss.com/auto-init.html